amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged IO_PAGE_FAULT
Laptop. GPU: Integrated AMD Radeon 780M, OS: Arch Linux, WM: Hyprland v0.39.1 (wayland). It happened also on Linux Mint 21.3 with Cinnamon (X11), so it seems it is not distribution or WM related.
Sometimes when I bring the screen (builtin) on after it gone off (powersaving, but not sleep, hibernation, etc) the screen is all white. Every time this happens I get this error.
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd800000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd801000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd802000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd803000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd804000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd805000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd806000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd807000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd808000 flags=0x0000]
Apr 21 17:17:31 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xffffd814000 flags=0x0000]

I tried to follow this, but setting iommu=soft does not help
Also always in dmesg output one can find a lot of following messages
Apr 21 17:08:59 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: Using 44-bit DMA addresses
Apr 21 17:09:59 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 1000 tries - dcn314_dsc_pg_control line:223
Apr 21 17:10:00 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100000 tries - optc1_wait_for_state line:839
Apr 21 17:10:00 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100000 tries - optc1_wait_for_state line:839
Apr 21 17:10:00 aleaf kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100000 tries - optc1_wait_for_state line:839

At boot there are some warnings and trace output about amdgpu, I leave it on pastebin

If this is reproducible under 6.8.7, report here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues

@ArtemS.Tashkinov, thanks, I found the same issue already open https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/3313
